# jQuery .on() not triggering the desired function

Tags: javascript, jquery, liquid

I have written some code to filter inside collections. But it doesn't trigger when the input clicked (checked with `console.log`)

Here's my code:

```
{% for collection in collections %}
  $('#collection-{{ collection.title | replace: " ", "" }}').on('click', function(event){
    showCollection('{{ collection.title | replace: " ", "" }}');
  });
{% endfor %}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
{% for collection in collections %}
   <li>
      <input type="radio" name="categoryCollection" id="collection-{{ collection.title | replace: " ", "" }}" value="{{ collection.title }}">
      <label for="collection-{{ collection.title | replace: " ", "" }}">{{ collection.title }}</label>
   </li>
{% endfor %}
```

What am I missing? Thanks!

EDIT:
The logic which I'm using is liquid, because I'm creating a Shopify theme. Also, in the console everything works fine.
I'll add here the rendered HTML:

```
<ul>
          
              
                <li>
                  <input type="radio" name="categoryCollection" id="collection-Jackets" value="Jackets">
                  <label for="collection-Jackets">Jackets</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="radio" name="categoryCollection" id="collection-LuxuryTracksuits" value="Luxury Tracksuits">
                  <label for="collection-LuxuryTracksuits">Luxury Tracksuits</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="radio" name="categoryCollection" id="collection-Masks" value="Masks">
                  <label for="collection-Masks">Masks</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="radio" name="categoryCollection" id="collection-T-Shirts" value="T-Shirts">
                  <label for="collection-T-Shirts">T-Shirts</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="radio" name="categoryCollection" id="collection-Trousers" value="Trousers">
                  <label for="collection-Trousers">Trousers</label>
                </li>
              
            </ul>
```

EDIT2: I created a working fiddle, that has only one problem: it works. [Here you can see it](https://jsfiddle.net/bencarafa/6edpq0w9/17/)

Comment: @RashedRahat https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/ or https://node-swig.github.io/swig-templates/ or any other...

Comment: Any  other special characters like quotes , comma, apostrophes or @ etc in the titles? Any errors thrown in dev tools console? Show a sample of generated code sent to browser

Comment: Do the elements exist in the DOM when the page loads?

Comment: It's only possible to guess what might be the problem.  You need to provide either example of `collections` (and what templating engine you are using) or **preferrably** the *rendered* HTML (which, when you look at it, you'll probably find your answer).

Comment: @freedomn-m I added the generated html, I don't see problems. Am I passing the function's parameters wrong in the .on()?

Comment: Change `$('#collection-{{ collection.title | replace: " ", "" }}').on('click', ...` to `$(document).on("click", '#collection-{{ collection.title | replace: " ", "" }}', ...` and see if it works

Comment: @freedomn-m nope, nothing

Comment: What is the order of execution of the two blocks you have shown? Like Rory wrote: do the elements exist when you bind the handler?

Comment: @trincot script loads right after the html has loaded, in fact they both are in the same file, with script being at the bottom

Comment: Can you provide a snippet that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Then there is nothing we can do... I would anyway suggest that you specify (as a tag) which templating library you are using (handlebars? mustache? ...), and specify the code in one piece, not in separated code blocks.

Comment: Double check the title case vs the case of string you are calling `showCollection()` with. I suspect that was your problem. The title would be `'Jackets'` but `id="collection_Jackets"` doesn't exist with the capital `J`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be made a lot more generic without needing a loop to create an event listener for each radio id.

Note the class added to each of the content elements in order to make hiding them generic also

Just take the value from the radio the event occurred on to filter out what you need to display

```js
$('.filter :radio[name="collection"]').change(function(){
    const content_id = 'collection_' + this.value.toLowerCase();
    $('.collection_content').hide().filter('#' + content_id).show();
});
```

```css
.collection_content{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="Jackets" value="Jackets" name="collection">
      <label for="jackets" >Jackets</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="Shirts" value="Shirts" name="collection">
      <label for="Shirts">shirts</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="Masks" value="Masks" name="collection">
      <label for="Masks">Masks</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="collection-wrap">
  <div id="collection_jackets" class="collection_content">JacketsJacketsJackets</div>
  <div id="collection_shirts" class="collection_content">ShirtsShirtsShirts</div>
  <div id="collection_masks" class="collection_content">MaksMaksMaks</div>
</div>
```

Comment: great approach, but still .change() doesn't trigger anything. Still, the approach is really good, I just simply can't make it work

Comment: Try `$(document).on('change', '.filter :radio[name="collection"]', function...`

Comment: Also add a `console.log('event occurred')` inside to see if event is captured in dev tools console. Need to narrow down why it is different than the working demo

Comment: done both, the function isn't triggered, the selector is right. Maybe is something in my code before?